# What is the difference between querying by distance and using the earthdistance module in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, geospatial

In postgres, there are two ways that I know of to query based on distance.

The first is "querying by distance" using a particular algorithm (as seen here http://daynebatten.com/2015/09/latitude-longitude-distance-sql/).

```
SELECT zcta.*, 
       3958.755864232 * 2 * 
       ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((41.318301 - zcta.latitude) * 
       PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(41.318301 * PI() / 180) * 
       COS(zcta.latitude * PI() / 180) * 
       POWER(SIN((-83.6174935 - zcta.longitude) * 
       PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, 
       MOD(CAST((ATAN2( ((zcta.longitude - -83.6174935) / 57.2957795),
       ((zcta.latitude - 41.318301) / 57.2957795)) * 
       57.2957795) + 360 AS decimal), 360) AS bearing 
  FROM "zcta" 
  WHERE (zcta.latitude BETWEEN 40.59464208444576 
                           AND 42.04195991555424 
         AND zcta.longitude BETWEEN -84.58101890178294 
                           AND -82.65396809821705 
         AND (3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((41.318301 - zcta.latitude) * 
              PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(41.318301 * PI() / 180) * COS(zcta.latitude * 
              PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-83.6174935 - zcta.longitude) * 
              PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) 
                  BETWEEN 0.0 
                      AND 50) 
 ORDER BY distance ASC
```

The second is the earthdistance module (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/earthdistance.html) for geospatial queries.

```
select * 
  from zcta 
 where earth_box(ll_to_earth(41.318301, -83.6174935), 63067.2) @> 
                  ll_to_earth(zcta.latitude, zcta.longitude)
```

What is the difference here? Which is better to use? Which is more accurate? How do each work?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer, but my addition.  The first is a roll-your-own solution, whereas the latter is a `Postgresql` `extension` or `module` called `earthdistance`.  To install, in `psql`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS earthdistance;
```

You might need to do the same for `cube` first as they share resources.  Or...

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS earthdistance CASCADE;
```

Here is the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/earthdistance.html).